# pandas.DataFrame.replace, and for the first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, dataframe

How to use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe?

This seems to be rather dumb question, but please [take a look here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/40a4efeafcaed5616d288dd05aff9d0d),

I.e., of the following three `DataFrame.replace`, only one is working, the other two are not. How can I fix them?

Also, how to limit the replacement within the first column? (I tried to use `, axis=1`, but was told that it is now deprecated). Thx.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], 100),
                   'B': np.random.choice(['one', 'two', 'three'], 100),
                   'C': np.random.choice(['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4'], 100),
                   'D': np.random.randint(-10,11,100),
                   'E': np.random.randn(100)})

p = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A','B'], columns='C', values='D')
df.replace("fo","fu", regex=True,inplace=True)
p.replace("fo","fu", regex=True,inplace=True)
p.index = p.index.to_series().str.join('-')
r=p.copy()
r.replace("fo","fu", regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Making replacements in just one column

Get that column as a Series and use the `Series.replace` method:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace("fo", "fu", regex=True)
```

or

```
df['A'].replace("fo", "fu", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

#### Making replacements in an index

Both `Series.replace` and `DataFrame.replace` act only on the data itself, not on the index. You need to reset the index to a column, make the replacement and set the index back again.

```
r = p.copy()
r.index = r.index.to_series().str.join('-')
r.index.name = 'A-B'

r = (r.reset_index()                     # reset the index
      .replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)   # make the replacement
      .set_index('A-B'))                 # set the index again
```

You can combine this with the above — so the replacement *only* happens in the index.

```
r = p.copy()
r.index = r.index.to_series().str.join('-')
r.index.name = 'A-B'

r = r.reset_index()
r['A-B'] = r['A-B'].replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)
r = r.set_index('A-B')
```

Even shorter is @juanpa.arrivillaga's code:

```
r.index = r.index.to_series().replace('fo','fu', regex=True)
```

#### Making replacements in a `MultiIndex`

Again, you need to reset whichever level of the `MultiIndex` you want, make the replacement and put it back in the index.

```
p = (p.reset_index(level='A')            # reset only level 'A'
      .replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)   # make the replacement
      .set_index('A', append=True)       # send 'A' to the index again
      .swaplevel())                      # if you want 'A' before 'B'
```

Or, to make the replacement *only* in that level of the index:

```
p = p.reset_index(level='A')
p['A'] = p['A'].replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)
p = p.set_index('A', append=True).swaplevel()
```

But notice that

```
p.index = p.index.to_series().replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)
```

does not quite give what you want here — it replace the `MultiIndex` with a plain index.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer. I'll check them out and get back to you. About replacement within the first column, how to reference it by index instead of field name? I'm writing a lib that doesn't know which exactly the first column field name is. Thx.

Comment: If you don't know that the name of the column is `A`, use `df.iloc[:,0]` instead of `df['A']`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your other two uses of replace is that replace only works on the values in the columns, not in the index, and in `p` and `r` 'fo' is only found in the index! So, one approach that would work is:

```
p.index = p.index.to_series().replace('fo','fu', regex=True)
r.index = r.index.to_series().replace('fo','fu', regex=True)
```

So, you see...

```
>>> r.index = r.index.to_series().replace('fo','fu', regex=True)
>>> r
C                I1        I2        I3        I4
bar-one    6.666667  1.875000 -3.750000  6.000000
bar-three -1.750000 -4.000000 -2.200000 -1.000000
bar-two    4.000000 -2.666667 -4.333333  4.000000
fuo-one    5.400000 -0.400000  4.000000  0.000000
fuo-three  0.166667 -4.500000 -5.000000 -5.571429
fuo-two    2.100000 -4.000000  4.500000 -1.857143
```

In general, if you only want to replace on a single column, you need to use something like:

```
df.loc[:,'B'].replace('th','TH', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

So...

```
>>> df.loc[:,'B'].replace('th','TH', regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df.head(10)
     A      B   C  D         E
0  bar    two  I3 -7  1.212562
1  bar    two  I3 -9  1.480350
2  bar    one  I2  1 -1.555152
3  fuo    two  I2 -9 -1.754800
4  bar    one  I3 -4  1.455140
5  fuo  THree  I4 -9  0.131374
6  fuo    one  I4 -7  1.876776
7  fuo    one  I1  3  0.170372
8  bar    two  I1  3 -0.647829
9  bar    one  I3 -1  0.796723
```

Note, the latter construct let's you control the rows as well!

```
>>> df.loc[0:5,'B'].replace('on','ON', regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df.head(10)
     A      B   C  D         E
0  bar    two  I3 -7  1.212562
1  bar    two  I3 -9  1.480350
2  bar    ONe  I2  1 -1.555152
3  fuo    two  I2 -9 -1.754800
4  bar    ONe  I3 -4  1.455140
5  fuo  THree  I4 -9  0.131374
6  fuo    one  I4 -7  1.876776
7  fuo    one  I1  3  0.170372
8  bar    two  I1  3 -0.647829
9  bar    one  I3 -1  0.796723
```

Comment: Hi, `p.index = p.index.to_series().replace('fo', 'fu', regex=True)` will replace the MultiIndex with a plain index, won't it? Not that it matters in my case, but want to confirm. Thx.

Comment: @xpt *Actually* it's giving me a segfault! Can you try that for me? I guess I had only tried it on my machine before *after* I had already done `p.index = p.index.to_series().str.join('-')`

Comment: it didn't segfault on me, but it didn't work either. I got `(foo, one)` in column `C`.